# Match Cell Values by Searching another Range Of Cells

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I need to match 3 rows of A thru C looking up their values in A4-I4 and J4 reserved for place holder X for cells not being used.

A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3

A4:J4 (10th column for placeholder X)

Example match 3 keywords for first row:
Apple Pear Orange (in cells A1 B1 C1)

These will be looked up in row 4 if all three are not found then should return 0, if all 3 match the then return 1 for true.

Example if only matching 1 keyword (unused cells replaced by X):
Apple X X

Here's an example of what I already have for the 1st row, but the problem with this is that it will return true even if only the 1st letter is entered:

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND(A1,A4:C4)),ISERROR(FIND(B1,A4:C4)),ISERROR(FIND(C1,A4:C4))),"0",1)
```

So the above is not working correctly!

I'm using Excel 2007

Comment: The formula below knowingly does not work but is only for an example to your code as to what I would like:
=IF(AND(A1=A5:C5,B1=A5:C5,C1=A5:C5),1,)

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding of the problem:
Find the values in cells `A1:C3` in the range `A4:J4` if found then show the value found otherwise show X *(it is cell `J4` used for this part of the formula?)*

However your sample formula is searching only range `A4:C4`, also it will return `“0”` or `1`, it will never return `X` or the value of the cell.

If the above is correct use this formula *(adjust the ranges as needed)*.

*Using `A6:C8` to show the results. Enter formula in `A6` then copy to `A6:C8`*

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$A$4:$I$4,0)),"X",A1)
```

[image]

Comment: Close except I didn't explain very well what the X is for, below is a closer formula but it's only for 2 search cells where I need 3 x 3.

Comment: EDIT:
Close except I didn't explain very well what the X is for, just ignore the X. The code I provided in orig post is closer to what I need with the exception that it returns true even if I enter the 1st letter in the first cell to search. I need it to match the whole word, not a partial match of a word.

Comment: Sorry can't help you if you do not explain what is required. The answer provided complies with what you originally asked for... show what you have done and what is not working

Comment: Sorry, it's just a little hard to explain in words opposed to a verbal explanation. Here's what I have that currently works but not to the degree I need.

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C$2,$L9:$Z9, 0)), 0, 1)

What I need is for 3 keywords/values in cells C2 D2 E2 to match if any of them are found in the range of L9:Z9. All 3 must match or return 0 for false. The X is only used as a filler in order to return true if I'm searching for only 1 or 2 keywords instead of all 3.

Comment: Do you realize that you keep changing the ranges? Before it was `A1:C3` and `A4:J4` now `L9:Z9`. Could you please post a simple and clear sample of: 1. your data and 2.expected results, don't use formulas just show the expected results, just insert a picture showing the headings _(update your question)_.